# Durabel queue in HA mirroring rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

My queues are  durable and Messages are persistent. 
I have setup 3 RabbitMQ Server Cluster having 
HA mirroring of all queues among all servers.
My Master node seems to be Rabbitmq3 When I shutdown RabbitmQ3.
I get following errors.

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbitmq3' of durable queue 'durable-test-queue' in vhost 'test' is down or inaccessible
```

> I think if I have mirrored queues in Cluster. I should not create
>   durable queue since they will cause problem if my rabbitmq master node
>   goes down suddenly

.

Or is there any solution to this problem.